# Why Is "Windows protecting people's PC" from my program? Can I get around it?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, conversion, anti-virus

I have a Batch program that I convert to exe using BattoEXE converter. It always triggers the smartscreen feature in windows 10. Why and how do I get around this?

Comment: Don't convert it to an executable? The only real reason to do so is to hide what it is doing and Windows Defender presumably isn't happy with that as it would be a common malware tactic.

Comment: Defender typically wouldn't ask you more than once, after attempting to run an untrusted application, once you indicated you wanted to actually run it.  This SmartScreen prompt is displayed, based on the reputation of the file itself, converting the batch script to a signed executable would solve this particular problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are other things considered, other than if an executable is signed.  SmartScreen uses several different sources of information and factors to consider if that particular prompt should be displayed.  To put it simply, it considers the reputation of the file, increasing the factors that improve the reputation of the file will prevent this prompt.  Typically, it is displayed once and isn't displayed again for the file for that user unless the file is changed.

Comment: Its my company's code so we want the script hidden. ah well, I'll Just have to deal.

Comment: @MarkDodsons And you think people can't reverse the conversion?  All that is effectively doing is making it harder for casual observers to see the contents of the batch file, anybody who is really determined (read as 'any less than honest competitors and any hackers') will be able to get to the code without much effort.

Comment: The main thing is that it allows me to include programs in the one executable. Can have 10 files in the one.

Comment: Look at using Iexpress.exe instead.